# How to make button's border invisible in Matlab's GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I set the background color of the button the same as the frame. However, it still has a border. Anyone knows how to make this border go away? Thanks a lot!

Btw I used guide to help. I looked up all the settings of it in guide. None of them is linked to the border...

[image]

Comment: Isn't it simpler to just make a keypress function on a textbox?

Comment: Have you looked here: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-uicontrol-border